# Upload images from Mobile to Server

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I'm developing a Xamarin.Forms application for Android and iOS that needs to take photos and upload its to a Server. Then, to take the photos on the client side, I'm using Xam.Plugin.Media.

But, as this plugin saves the photos in Xamarin.Forms.Image format and I need them in the System.Drawing.Image format on the Server side, first I tried to save the photo taken by Xam.Plugin.Media in a Byte array, upload it to the server and then save the Bytes array in System.Drawing.Image format, but do not work.

After, I searched for several days in the Internet how to convert the formats and I didn't find anything useful, either converting on the mobile side using Xamarin or on the Server side using C#.

Can anyone help me in this challenge?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my poor English.

Marcelo Camarate

Comment: In my opinion, using a base64 string is better for sending images or files to a server.

Comment: What are you talking about?  Images are saved in whatever the native format for the device is - typically jpg.  `Xamarin.Forms.Image` is a UI control, not an image format.  There are numerous existing questions about uploading images.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would use `MediaPicker` from [Xamarin Essentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/media-picker?tabs=android) rather than the outdated media plugin. Second, the `FileResult` you get back provides access to a `Stream` which you can copy to a `MemoryStream` ahich you can copy to a byte array with `MemoryStream.ToArray()` which gives you your `byte[]`. You can see an example on the page I link to of how to get the stream from the photo and the various docs for the other methods to find out what you need.

You can then upload the bytes however you want based on your server API.